# undefined method 'password=' for #<User:0xb88ac38>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Micropost Model using the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code:sample_microposts tutorial. while running a test to  verify that a micropost object responds to the content and user_id attributes i get this error
 undefined method 'password=' for #  Below are the code blocks for "User.rb" &     "Micropost spec.rb".

```
   **User.rb**

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :arts
    belongs_to :account
     attr_accessible :name, :email,:password, :password_confirmation

       has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
       has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
    has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
      has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

     def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
     end

      def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
    end

     def unfollow!(other_user)
      relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
    end
        def accountName
        account.name
```

***Micropost_spec***

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Micropost do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    # This code is wrong!
    @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)
  end

  subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }

end
```

**Migration Users**

> class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration   def change
>       create_table :users do |t|
>         t.string :name
>         t.string :category
>
> ```
>   t.timestamps
> end   end end
> ```

**User Model**

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base   has_many :arts  belongs_to :account
>     has_secure_password
>          attr_accessible :name, :email
>          has_many :microposts
>
> ```
>    before_create { generate_token(:auth_token)}
>    has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
>    has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed   has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key:
> ```
>
> "followed_id",
>                                      class_name:  "Relationship",
>                                      dependent:   :destroy
>         has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
>
> def generate_token(column)
>       begin
>          self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
>          end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
>
> ```
>  def following?(other_user)
> relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)   end
> ```
>
> def follow!(other_user)
>       relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)   end
>         def unfollow!(other_user)
>       relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy   end        def accountName         account.name
>       end   end end

Comment: Can you point us to what `has_secure_password` does?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess into the blue, but looking at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec:adding_a_secure_password it seems like you're missing the passwords part.

If this is not the case, then you may need to post your complete model (it looks like it is cutted off) and maybe your migration file for users.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have put in my migration file for user above, when you say model, do you mean, micropost or user model?

Comment: user model, since your user needs to authenticate with a password

Comment: i have inserted my user model above